# Getting file time using stat & tm structor in Linux

Tags: c, linux, stat, localtime

I using g++ on linux with eclipse. I am making a code that get file's time and output file's month,hour,etc...

While debugging, the value of `time1` changed unexpectedly but I have no idea about this issue.

What is problem of this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>


struct stat stat1, stat2;
struct tm *time1, *time2;

void filestat1(void);
void filestat2(void);
void filetime1(void);
void filetime2(void);
void datecmp(void);
void timecmp(void);

int main(void)
{
    filestat1();
    filestat2();
    filetime1();
    filetime2();
    datecmp();
    timecmp();
}

void filestat1(void)
{
    // check if there is no text1
    int check = 0;
    check = stat("text1", &stat1);    

    if(check != 0)
    {
        printf("Error : there is no text1\n");
    }
    return;
}


void filestat2(void)
{
    // check if there is no text2
    int check = 0;
    check = stat("text2", &stat2);    

    if(check != 0)
    {
        printf("Error : there is no text2\n");
    }
    return;
}


void filetime1(void)
{
    time1 = localtime(&stat1.st_mtime); //!!! this change unexpectedly
    return;
}


void filetime2(void)
{
    time2 = localtime(&stat2.st_mtime);    

    return;
}    

void datecmp(void)
{
    printf("date compare\n");
    // compare tm_mon
    if(time1->tm_mon > time2->tm_mon)
        printf("time1 is early \n");
    else if(time1->tm_mon < time2->tm_mon)
        printf("time2 is early \n");
    else{
        // compare tm_mday
        if(time1->tm_mday > time2->tm_mday)
            printf("time1 is early \n");
        else if(time1->tm_mday < time2->tm_mday)
            printf("time2 is early \n");
        // same date
        else
            printf("same time \n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}


void timecmp(void)
{

printf(time1->tm_hour);
printf(time2->tm_hour);
printf("time compare\n");
// compare hour
if(time1->tm_hour > time2->tm_hour)
    printf("time1 is early \n");
else if(time1->tm_hour < time2->tm_hour)
    printf("time2 is early \n");
else{
    // compare minutes
    if(time1->tm_min > time2->tm_min)
        printf("time1 is early \n");
    else if(time1->tm_min < time2->tm_min)
        printf("time2 is early \n");
    // same time
    else
        printf("same time \n");

    }
}
```

Comment: Although you originally tagged and mention `g++`, your code is C, not C++, so I have adjusted the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using global variables, completely unnecessarily, making your life harder than it has to be. It is very hard for us humans to track where global variables are modified, especially when you have several global variables with very similar names.

So, instead of trying to unravel all that, let's rewrite it using function parameters, without any global variables at all.

First, we tell the C library we want POSIX.1-2008 features, and include the headers that expose the functionality we need:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

Next, let's define a function that takes a file name as a parameter, and pointers to where the function can store the last access and last modification timestamps. If the function is successful, it'll return 0; otherwise, it'll return -1 with `errno` set to indicate the error.

```
int filetime(const char *path,
             time_t *accessed, long *accessed_nsec,
             time_t *modified, long *modified_nsec)
{
    struct stat  info;

    /* Path must not be NULL or empty. */
    if (!path || !path[0]) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Get file statistics. */
    if (stat(path, &info) == -1)
        return -1; /* errno was set by stat() */

    /* Save timestamps. */
    if (accessed)
        *accessed = info.st_atim.tv_sec;
    if (accessed_nsec)
        *accessed_nsec = info.st_atim.tv_nsec;
    if (modified)
        *modified = info.st_mtim.tv_sec;
    if (modified_nsec)
        *modified_nsec = info.st_mtim.tv_nsec;

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}
```

Let's continue by writing a simple `main()`, that takes one or more file names as command-line parameters, and describes them. I like to start the main by checking the number of command line arguments, and if specified, the first argument. If none, or the first one is `-h` or `--help`, I like to print the usage of the utility. This way, I can keep my example programs in their own directories, and to find one I'm looking for, I can just execute each one without parameters, to see what each of them does. It's much faster than reading the sources!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILENAME ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program will print the last access and\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "last modification timestamps for each of\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "the specified files.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Because there is at least one, but possibly more than one file name parameter, we handle each of them in a loop:

```
    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        time_t     accessed, modified;
        long       accessed_ns, modified_ns;
        struct tm  accessed_localtime, modified_localtime;
```

Within the loop, we first call our `filetime()` function. Note how we have declared the variables we want filled above, and how we call the function: `&accessed` yields a pointer to `accessed`.

```
        if (filetime(argv[arg], &accessed, &accessed_ns,
                                &modified, &modified_ns)) {
            /* Nonzero return value, so an error occurred! */
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

In C, function parameters are passed by value, not by reference. This means that if a function parameter is say `int foo`, any changes to `foo` within the function are visible within the function only; the changes are not visible to the caller. When we pass a pointer to a variable, say `int *foo`, then changes to `foo` are still visible only within the function, but `*foo` refers to the value pointed at by the pointer; and changes to *that* are visible to the caller.

In short, when we want a function to be able to modify the value of a variable, we use a pointer. That's just how C works.

Now that we have the times in Unix Epoch time (`time_t`), we want to split them into local time fields:

```
        if (!localtime_r(&accessed, &accessed_localtime) ||
            !localtime_r(&modified, &modified_localtime)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot compute timestamps in local time: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

Note that I again used a POSIX.1-2008 function, [`localtime_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime_r.3.html). In tutorials, you often see the older `localtime()` used instead, but that one may use a global variable internally (it can always return a pointer to the same structure, reusing it for every call); `localtime_r()` is better.

See how the second parameter to `localtime_r` is also a pointer (to a `struct tm`)? Again, this is just how you do functions that change some values in a way that is visible to the caller.

Also, it is rare for `localtime_r()` (or `localtime()`) to fail, so many simply ignore checking it for errors. There is no excuse for that, as it's just a couple of lines more code, and if an error does occur at some point, the user will be immensely more satisfied with a clear error code, rather than just seeing the program crash due to segmentation fault.

All that is left, is to print out the information gathered. I like to use a variant the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) international standard for the time format; in particular, it sorts in proper time order even if sorted alphabetically. (My variant is that I like to use a space, and not a `T`, between the date and the time.)

```
        printf("%s:\n", argv[arg]); /* The file name or path */

        printf("    Modified: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n",
               modified_localtime.tm_year + 1900,
               modified_localtime.tm_mon + 1,
               modified_localtime.tm_mday,
               modified_localtime.tm_hour,
               modified_localtime.tm_min,
               modified_localtime.tm_sec,
               modified_ns / 1000000L);

        printf("    Accessed: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n",
               accessed_localtime.tm_year + 1900,
               accessed_localtime.tm_mon + 1,
               accessed_localtime.tm_mday,
               accessed_localtime.tm_hour,
               accessed_localtime.tm_min,
               accessed_localtime.tm_sec,
               accessed_ns / 1000000L);

        /* Make sure everything written to stdout
           is actually written to standard output right now. */
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `fflush(stdout)` tells the C library to ensure all preceding writes to `stdout` are actually written to the standard output. (By default, `stdout` is buffered, and `stderr` is unbuffered.) Normally, the C library will flush the output at every newline, but having the explicit flush there also reminds us human programmers that we want everything thus far printed, to actually appear on the programs standard output at that point. (This way, if one of the files is on some slow filesystem, say old USB stick or a network share, the information on previous files gets shown before the program accesses the slow file. Essentially, the "stall" will occur at the expected place for the human users.)

It is probably a good idea to mention [`relatime`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatime#Criticism_of_atime) and other related mount options at this point. In simple terms, it means that to avoid the number of writes to storage media due to read accesses, the access time is not always updated. So, if you don't see it changing even after you read a file (using e.g. `cat FILENAME >/dev/null`), it just means your system has mount options enabled that reduce the access time updates to speed up your filesystem access and reduce the number of writes to it. It is a good option; I use it.

Finally, most Linux filesystems do not have a *created* timestamp at all. The `st_ctime` (and `st_ctim.tv_sec` and `st_ctim.tv_nsec`) fields refer to *last status change* timestamp. It tracks changes to the owner, group, permissions, and the number of hard links.

When you examine the above code, especially the `if` clauses, it is useful to remember that in C, the logical OR operation, `||`, is short-circuiting: the left side is evaluated first, but if it fails, the right side is not evaluated at all. So, if you have e.g. `int x = 1, y = 0;` and you do `(x == 0 || ++y)`, `y` will not be incremented at all. I utilize this when examining `argv[1]` in the very first `if` clause in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

`localtime` returns a pointer to a static structure. You need to copy the result before calling `localtime` again.

I would declare `time1` and `time2` as structures instead of pointers to store the values.

```
struct tm time1, time2;

void filetime1(void)
{
    struct tm *tmp = localtime(&stat1.st_mtime);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        //... handle error
    }
    time1 = *tmp;
}
```

Similarly for `filetime2`.

If you are writing multi-threaded code, it is safer to use the reentrant variant of the function, `localtime_r`. In that case, you pass in the pointer to the structure for the result.

```
void filetime1(void)
{
    struct tm *tmp = localtime_r(&stat1.st_mtime, &time1);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        //... handle error
    } else {
        assert(tmp == &time1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that OK out of `filetime` function? Can I use it?

Comment: ../main.c:87: filetime2: Assertion `tmp == &time1` failed.
I included `assert.h`, but it does not work.

Comment: `filetime2` should use `time2`, even in the assertion.

Comment: Oh.. sorry i missed. I will change it

Comment: I am trying to use your advice2, but i output error.
../main.c:87: filetime2: Assertion `tmp == &time2' failed.
Also, while debugging, time1 and time2 can not get value.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://tio.run/##dY/RboMgFIbveYqTLjNonFtv69yLbI1hiJZEwMDRpFn67A6oizVduSCH7/z/fzj8peN8fpKa92Mj4N1hI01x@iA36Oxe8TwId48dMtzSUUsfsWUoldgS5pywwTk7tCNHQAVBtS/JAkJyvDwik5ENtLIXUUPDMyU/BPxZ/RmqASroDWd90NWWJjGgcFirQHJIYkBaRuv1EzTaqrV1IURqBMWkBhoqZjueAz8xC5mvp89jCn/DGdKI3o4@PE5bwgfrrS3dKaPhW7TGigM8N196l18XLVDVvreo193@sbMWhX3kvszzLw